# Javascript value to div

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

This script is meant to return a country when a phone number is queried.
On the browser console; if you query: `e164.lookup('12045551234')` it will return `Object {Country: "Canada"}` I want to display this result in `countrydiv` and also get phone number value from `phonediv`. Here is the code.

```js
! function() {
    var t, e = {
        1201: ["-4", "United States"],
        1202: ["-4", "United States"],
        1203: ["-4", "United States"],
        1204: ["-4", "Canada"],
        1205: ["-4", "United States"],
        1206: ["-4", "United States"],
        1207: ["-4", "United States"],
        };
    t = function(t) {
        if (t.length) {
            var a, S = t.length;
            for (S; S >= 0; S -= 1)
                if (a = t.substring(0, S), e[a])
                    return {
                         Country: e[a][1]

                    }

        }
    }, "undefined" != typeof exports && (exports.lookup = t),
    "undefined" != typeof window && (window.e164 = {
        lookup: t
    })
}();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="phonediv">9956335486352</div>
    <div id="countrydiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the specific question that isn't answerable with a reasonable web search? What did you try so far? What went wrong? Or is it just "I have absolutely no idea how to do this and my company restricts access to Google"? This sounds meaner than it is: the point is that updating an HTML element with a string is easy to search for. And why bother nesting it in its own object? Just return the name string.

Comment: document.getElementById('countrydiv').innerHTML = Object.country;

Comment: Did you take this code from some mangled code? Suggest giving your variables meaningful names.

Answer (score 0):

use the `innerHTML` or `innerText` property in Javascript for inserting the text inside the `countrydiv` division. Here's an example i wrote for you. Thanks :)

```
var element = document.getElementById('countrydiv');
element.innerHTML = e164.lookup('12045551234').Country;
```

Or

```
 var obj = e164.lookup('12045551234');
 var element = document.getElementById('countrydiv');
  element.innerHTML = obj.Country;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently invoking your function as soon as you create it. This won't do the user any good because there won't be any data in the div when you call the function. If I understand what you want to accomplish, then you're going to want to name your country lookup function (we'll call it lookup) and you're going to want to add an event listener to the telephone number div to call the function when the content of the div changes. If you want users to be able to enter phone numbers into this div I would also suggest changing your div to an input field to make sure that the onchange event listener works in a broader variety of browsers.

On the note of browser compatibility, I used querySelector instead of getElementById as it is better supported in my experience.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function lookup () {
        var t, e = {
            1201: ["-4", "United States"],
            1202: ["-4", "United States"],
            1203: ["-4", "United States"],
            1204: ["-4", "Canada"],
            1205: ["-4", "United States"],
            1206: ["-4", "United States"],
            1207: ["-4", "United States"],
            };
        t = function(t) {
            if (t.length) {
                var a, S = t.length;
                for (S; S >= 0; S -= 1)
                    if (a = t.substring(0, S), e[a])
                        var countrydiv = document.querySelector("#countrydiv");
                        countrydiv.innerHTML = e[a][1];
                        return {
                             Country: e[a][1]
                        }
            }
        }, "undefined" != typeof exports && (exports.lookup = t),
        "undefined" != typeof window && (window.e164 = {
            lookup: t
        })
    }

    var phonediv = document.querySelector("#phonediv");
    phonediv.addEventListener("change", lookup);
    </script>
    <div id="phonediv">9956335486352</div>
    <div id="countrydiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This pattern is node js, I need a client-side implementation. (not working like this). Thanks

Comment: Client side implementation can mean a lot of things. Is the phone div automatically populated with a phone number on the server side? If so, why are you using client side JS to detect the country of the phone number?

If you're trying to detect the country after a user enters a phone number, you will need to create a field a user can edit using html first as I suggested before. If you haven't already, try replacing <div id="phonediv></div> with <input type="text" id="phonediv">. It is possible that the change listener can work with contenteditable, but save yourself the hassle and use a field.